# How to process each frame of a video and shift pixels between frames using android camera2

Tags: android-camera2

I am new to android, and in my application I need to receive video from the camera and mix pixels from different frames. I tried to get frames from the captured video using mediaMetaDataRetriever, but it's taking too long. Now I use ImageReader to get each real-time frame, create a bitmap and put it in an array. This takes up VERY MUCH RAM space. and the subsequent processing of this array with three cycles is also quite long.
So how do I solve this problem with Camera2?

Mixing array of Bitmap:

```
 val outputFrames = arrayOfNulls<Bitmap>(1080)
    var videoDuration = frames.size
    if(videoDuration%2 != 0) videoDuration--
    var index = 0
    while (index < videoDuration) {
        var indexWidth = 1079
        while (indexWidth >= 0) {
            var indexHeight = 1919
            while (indexHeight >= 0) {
                if (outputFrames[indexWidth] == null) {
                    outputFrames[indexWidth] =
                        Bitmap.createBitmap(videoDuration, 1920, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                    outputFrames[indexWidth]!![index, indexHeight] =
                        frames[0][indexWidth, indexHeight]
                } else outputFrames[indexWidth]!![index, indexHeight] =
                    frames[0][indexWidth, indexHeight]
                //Log.e("frame:", "$indexWidth $indexHeight /${outputFrames[indexWidth]}/")
                indexHeight--
            }
            indexWidth--
        }
        frames.removeAt(0)
        index++
    }
```

My Image Reader:

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth,mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888,1)
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
        { reader ->
            val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
            val planes = image.planes
            val buffer = planes[0].buffer
            val offset = 0
            val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
            val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
            val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth
            // create bitmap
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride,
                mHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
            image.close()

        },
        mBackgroundHandler)
```

Comment: What mixing are you trying to do? Where are you storing the bitmaps you create in the ImageReader listener, and how many are you keeping at the same time?

Comment: @Eddy if you imagine the video as a three-dimensional array of pixels, then I want to make a video that plays as if from the side, because of which each frame of the new video should contain pixels from all the captured frames.  Unfortunately now I haven’t come up with a better way than storing all the bitmaps in the array at the same time, their number depends on the duration of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Bitmap is very expensive and it will slow down your App like hell. Try to get your Image as:

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

After that you can create your Bitmap by using an ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB like:

```
Image.Plane Y = mImage.getPlanes()[0];
        Image.Plane U = mImage.getPlanes()[1];
        Image.Plane V = mImage.getPlanes()[2];

        int Yb = Y.getBuffer().remaining();
        int Ub = U.getBuffer().remaining();
        int Vb = V.getBuffer().remaining();

        byte[] data = new byte[Yb + Ub + Vb];

        Y.getBuffer().get(data, 0, Yb);
        V.getBuffer().get(data, Yb, Vb);
        U.getBuffer().get(data, Yb + Vb, Ub);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(Main2Activity.this);
        ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

        Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(data.length);
        Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(DISPLAY_WIDTH).setY(DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        final Bitmap bmpout = Bitmap.createBitmap(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        in.copyFromUnchecked(data);

        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);
        out.copyTo(bmpout);
```

This code will speed up everything drastically if you use it in a background thread.